# How does the update process work for different install methods?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, software-updates

From my understanding there are four ways to install packages:

1. Build from source and install
2. Install binary
3. Install a `deb/rpm` file
4. Install from repository

In Ubuntu for example, are packages installed using all methods updated when running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y;`?

My understanding is that this process only updates packages installed from repositories. Could a binary or source code installation have code in the installer to let the package manager know where to get future updates? Would this mean that the package manager can update binary / build from source installations too?

Comment: also asked on [ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/826141/421483)

Comment: Yes, after posting to ubuntu I thought that people using other distributions might find this useful too.